# Compute $E(X e^{X-Y})$ for discrete and independent $X$ and $Y$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation, independence

I have been giving two discrete random variables $X$ and $  Y$ and their probability distribution functions.

$X$ and $ Y$ are independent of each other.

I have to calculate $E(Xe^{X-Y})$. I know what the answer is, since that has been given to me, but I would like to know how to solve especially the part containing $e^{X-Y}$.

First of all, since X and Y are independent, can I split it up so that it becomes $E(X)\cdot E(e^{X-Y})?$

Furthermore, if it was just $e^X$ for instance, then I would just use the probability distribution function for $X$ and calculate $P_1e^{X_1} + P_2e^{X_2} + \ldots + P_ne^{X_n}$.

How do I deal with specifically this kind of exercise?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Please take a look at [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to make your posts look better when entering math symbols. Cheers!

Comment: It is the case in general that given two independent r.v.s $X$ and $Y$, then functions of them $f(X),g(Y)$ are independent r.v.s., so $X e^X$ and $e^{-Y}$ are independent.

Comment: @GeorgeN.Missailidis Using `\land` for the word `and` is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot split $EXe^{X-Y}$ to $EX\; Ee^{X-Y}$ since $X$ and $e^{X-Y}$ are dependent, in general. But you can split it to
$$EXe^{X-Y} = EXe^X \; Ee^{-Y}$$
since $Xe^X$ and $e^{-Y}$ are independent. Then calculate both as you wrote above:
$$EXe^X = x_1e^{x_1}p_1+x_2e^{x_2}p_2+\ldots,$$
$$Ee^{-Y}=e^{-y_1}q_1+e^{-y_2}q_2+\ldots,$$
where $P(X=x_i)=p_i$, $P(Y=y_i)=q_i$.